# Incorrect row height when using multiple rowspan

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

**Edit: Please, consider the example of my last edit.**

This is something that always worked with Chrome, Edge or IE, but never with Firefox, and this bug started happening on Chrome's last update (57).
When I'm using multiple rowspan and some table cell has 2 or more lines, the consecutive row height is not working properly.

Honestly, my english is a working in progress and it's hard to explain, so I created an example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqoZZj

**CSS**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.column-product {
  width: 30px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column-product">Product</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- 1st product -->
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Epic Shorts</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10.20</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- 2nd product -->
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5">Cool T-Shirt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Black</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>7.10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the product "*Epic Shorts*" just have one variation - but it has 2 lines, and the consecutive row's height is not following the principal row height.
The issue didn't happen with the product "*Cool T-Shirt*", because it has 2 variations (Black and Green).

**What is the desirable result?**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpMyWX

The only change I did was forcing the height of the row:

```
<!-- 1st product -->
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3">Epic Shorts</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">Blue</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 39px;"> <!-- HERE -->
  <td>1</td>
  <td>10.20</td>
</tr>
```

Honestly, it's not a viable solution because I can't predict the principal row's height- it's automatic.

It's working properly on Edge or Internet Explorer (sweet irony).

Any help would be appreciated. I'll do my best to explain better.

Thank you.

**Edit: Image to show differences:**

[image: Differences]

**Edit:**

First of all, I appreciate all answers. Second, my apologies, I missed another example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpeXGY

I added another variantion of "Black" of "Cool T-Shirt", and that can happen.
[image: Example]

Comment: I don't see any issues (or any difference between Chrome and Firefox) on this code behavior. Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Sure, just added the screenshot.

Comment: Here is my screenshot: I see something strange on Firefox... but not in Chrome... http://imgur.com/a/BW62L (Cant test on IE/Edge)

Comment: Thank you @jaumemk.

Comment: Awesome, someone just downvoted my question and don't even told me why. How could I learn or have progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should read some basic tutorials about building a table .

You have 4 headers, which expect rows(tr) of four cells too.

Your tables here is made of 4 rows , 1 `tr` = 1 row . You need 4 `<tr>` to build it

`rowspan` can be used once here, when 1 product has different colors for example.

```css
th,td {border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column-product">Product</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <!-- TOTAL : 4 CELLS -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- 1st product -->
    <tr>
      <th>Epic Shorts</th><!-- you can use a header here too -->
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10.20</td>
      <!-- TOTAL : 4 CELLS -->
    </tr>
    <!-- 2nd product -->
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Cool T-Shirt</th><!-- will span to next row -->
      <td>Black</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10.00</td>
      <!-- TOTAL : 4 CELLS -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- [Cool T-Shirt] is spanning down here -->
      <td>Green</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>7.10</td>
      <!-- TOTAL : 4 CELLS (1 spanning)-->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please, could you check my edit?

And please understand, you may think not, but I understand how tables works. It's not a simple scenario that I'm showing, and by design, it's possible to do with tables/rowspan. The way rowspan works always made this scenario possible in all browsers I worked(Chrome(Blink/WebKit), Safari(macOS/iOS), IE, Edge, Android, etc...) but Firefox. It's not something I missed or I need to "read some basic tutorials about building a table".
Firefox has a issue about this bug since 2008: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431403

Comment: @jaumemk posted this screenshot showing the bug is not happening on Chrome nor Firefox on Linux.
http://imgur.com/a/BW62L

Anyway, I appreciate your time to help me. I hope we both could learn something from this.

Comment: @KimTranjan hello, just saw your update and codepen :  i forked the way it would be build in my own humble opinion  : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zZVwNX a screan reader could help to find out if your go is a proper way to tag your datas ;)

Comment: @KimTranjan added comments in html to explain why i believe this is a correct structure . ;)

Comment: Thank you @GCyrillus! <3